# Finding elements on a matrix with indexes from another array - python

Tags: python, arrays

Sorry if this question was already answered somewhere, but i couldn't find what i was looking for!

So, say that i have a matrix/array like this

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

with an array like the one below, which is supposed to indicate element indexes that i want to retrieve for the matrix above...

```
b = [2,0,1] # get the 2nd element from a[0], the 0th from a[1] and 1st from a[2]
```

What i want is something like

```
c = magic (a,b)
c = [3,4,8] # elements correspondent with the indexes from b
```

The catch is, i wanna do that WITHOUT LOOPS (no for/while or similars)
I've tried doing something like this...

```
c = a[:,b[:]]
```

but no avail.... Is there something else i could try?

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension like:

```
   c = [ a[indx][b[indx]] for indx in range(len(b)) ]
   print c #[3, 4, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list-comprehension and `zip` to achieve that:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
b = [2,0,1]
c = [a[i][j] for i,j in zip(range(len(b)), b)]
print(c)
# Output [3, 4, 8]
```